# How to install vmwave without GUI on Linux?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vmware, virtual-machine

I need to Install a software, and this software only can run in the Windows Server system. But I don't have Windows Server, I have Ubuntu Server.

I want install a virtual machine Windows on this Ubuntu Server, but it non GUI, how can I install it?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Server

Answer (score 0):

You need to install desktop package like gnome, kde, lxde on your ubuntu server first and need to install linux version of vmware.

Answer (score 0):

```
env TERM=dumb VMWARE_EULAS_AGREED=yes ./VMware*.bundle --console --required
```